# Combine preference and headers in android settings

Tags: android, switch-statement, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I'm relatively new to the android development but one thing stumbled me - was preference-headers a half-baked feature? It's supposedly a new way forward for application development. However, from what I understand, headers are used for top-level categories only (hence headers). And you cannot mix headers and preferences? My application doesn't have a huge menu structure. As such, creating preference-header based menu is awkward as each header would lead to ~2-3 preferences. There is one header that has quite a few settings and for it I use a master switch.

My question is as follows. Can I combine preferences and headers or should I go 100% legacy way?

That is, can header list (root menu) be prepanded with preferences so that you get like a list preference (list dialog on click), edit text preference (edit text dialog on click), and headers (fragments on click)?

Or is using legacy way still acceptable for applications with few configuration options? If so, can a master switch be implemented there? For example, extending a preference screen and programmatically altering the layout to render the switch that would correspond to a switch in the sub-category?

If this isn't the right place to ask this question, please let me know where I should ask it. Thanks!!

Comment: Just as a comment to self, I guess, PreferenceScreen is a final class and cannot be extended further.